# Which option to select for Laptop's webcam while compiling linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04, linux-device-driver, webcam

I've ubuntu on my system and my webcam works with this. When i compiled the newer kernel my webcam is not working. The obvious cause is that i haven't compiled the required driver.
I believe USBIP is the thing that i need to choose but i'm not able to find it while compiling kernel using menuconfig.
Please help

Comment: This site is for programming questions. System configuration is offtopic.

Comment: Compiling a kernel is a programming task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the config for the running kernel in /boot/config-$(uname -r).  Copy that file to .config and do make oldconfig to merge it to your new kernel.